# Language Switcher plugin for WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a client project where he wants to add a language switcher. I search over the inter to find the one but the problem is all of them are switching text by their own code. I want to add my own Hindi text on the website.

For example :

Welcome-> after language switch( आपका स्वागत है )

Can someone suggest to me how to do this in WordPress?

Comment: That depends on the plugin you're using for the language switcher. In case you're using Polylang, there is a filter named `pll_flag_title` that you can use to customize the switcher's text: https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/filter-reference/

Comment: @Damocles Thanks. I will look for this